# Arraylist not having all values

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get all contacts and their numbers from the phone, when i try to print the values after they are retrieved, the array seems to be cut and does not print almost half the result, why could this be happening but in the listview all is printed. The snippet is as below

```
String namearray[];
String phonearray[];

lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
    //Read Contact Name
    String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

    //Read Phone Number
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    namecsv += name + ",";
    phonecsv += phoneNumber + ",";
}
phones.close();


//==============================================
// Convert csvstrimg into array
//==============================================
namearray = namecsv.split(",");
phonearray = phonecsv.split(",");

System.out.println("Names: " +phonecsv.toString());

//Create Array Adapter and Pass ArrayOfValues to it.
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,namearray);

//BindAdpater with our Actual ListView
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a note: do not concatenate `String`s inside loops, use `StringBuilder`or `StringBuffer` instead.

Comment: You are printing phonecsv while showing namearray in ListView, could it be that some names do not have corresponding phone numbers?

Comment: @manfcas Only `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer` is outdated.

Comment: @Tom Why is outdated? `StringBuilder` is optimized for single-thread use, while `StringBuffer` is thread safe.

Comment: you are not prinitng the arrays but the phonecv string, could this be the problem, you are using namearray  for the view

Comment: Its afirmative, i have more numbers than names also, 678 names and 820 numbers some are duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to print it all out in one line, you could try iterating through the ArrayList and printing each line separately. This assumes that phonecsv is an ArrayList< String>:

```
        for (String temp : phonecsv) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
```